# Magento IN email invoices showing multiple currency symbols

Tags: magento-1, email, invoice, currency, totals

[image]

Hi I am having problem with currencies which repeats twice.. in order invoice and order mails too..

Can anybody help me pls?

Comment: am using magento version 1.7.2